# catalog price rules will not work after mid night in magento site

Tags: magento, cron

We have a problem with catalog price rules in 1.9.0

We uploaded `1000` products in a site.

After catalog price rules to give discount for `500` products, there is no date limit for catalog price rules. Those special prices are displaying only until mid-night.

Next day, after mid-night, special prices are not displaying in site.

cron job is working fine.

Please help me to find some solution.

Answer (score 1):

this issue was only solved for me with this:

The problem is in `Mage_CatalogRule_Model_Action_Index_Refresh::execute()` function. You will have to rewrite this function/class either in your extension, or via the local version of the file.

You have to replace line 121 here :

```
app/code/core/Mage/CatalogRule/Model/Action/Index/Refresh.php

$timestamp = $coreDate->gmtTimestamp('Today');
```

with this line:

```
$timestamp = Mage::app()->getLocale()->date(null, null, null, true)->get(Zend_Date::TIMESTAMP);
```

view the original post:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/67970/catalog-price-rules-disappear-after-mid-night

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:** 
Please make sure that Cron is working fine. For this you can install `AOE Scheduler` extension.

**Step 2:** 
You need to debug the issue by debugging magento tables. Following tables used for catalog rules:

```
catalogrule
catalogrule_affected_product
catalogrule_customer_group
catalogrule_group_website
catalogrule_product
catalogrule_product_price
catalogrule_website
```

You can delete all catalog rules and create one single rule for one product and check following tables:

`catalogrule_product` - In this table Magento will manage all product discount percent for all customer group. 
`catalogrule_product_price` - In this table Magento will manage discounted final price for each product. Here magento will insert three days record for each record. you can check this by "rule_date" field.

If it is work perfectly. Then Again After deleting all Catalog rules again, Please truncate following tables from MySQL.

```
catalogrule_product
catalogrule_product_price
```

As due to many records primary key reach on maximum limit and try again by creating rule for 500 products. hope it will start work.

Hope this help!!

Comment: thanks a lot for reply, please check here : http://prntscr.com/75e1fb i used this extension : magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/aoe-scheduler.html i am getting message as in the image. i hope cron job is working fine. if so please inform me.  and i will look at the step 2 now......

Comment: Yes cron is working fine. If answer worked you then please accept and upvote the answer so that other will get benefit too.

Comment: ya, sure i will do that..... cron is working fine but catalog price rules are giving problem. as this is a live site, i am really not in a position to disable all catalog price rules and to to apply catalog price rule for only one product.

Comment: this is catalogrule_product_price table :  http://prntscr.com/75e80b can you please check and tell is there anything wrong?

Comment: in above image it showing, it is applying for all 3 days, but why it disappearing after mid night, please help 

about this....

Comment: From image it shows that primary key not reached to max limit. May be this will solve your issue : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25280095/magento-catalog-price-rule-disappears-at-night?rq=1

Comment: as i  am new to magento, how you found out "primary key" is not reached to maximium limit....

Answer (score 0):

As stated above by @Davi-Reinoldo the problem is with the indexer.

I had this problem as well, the issue exists when there is an offset of the local timezone greater than +01:00.

Basically just because magento is using the gmtTimestamp for the rule date which in the above stated case results in the day before today.

Therefor I developed a small module https://github.com/Chuvisco88/Chuvisco_CatalogRuleFix to fix the issue.
If someone ever has this problem, please give it a try.