# Magento promotions price deactivated each day

Tags: magento, promotions

I am using magento 1.8 and i have created promotions on catalogs.

its working perfectly but, after 24 hour the rule will be deactivated automatically but still on website home page the promotion pricse is shown.

once you clicked on the product you will get the original price only unless if i opened the promotions rule and click on Save & apply then i will get the promotion price working for 24 hours only.

i tried to make start end date for 1 month but same issue.
also i tried with cron job and still same issue.

i searched all over solutions on google but i didn't get any solution yet.

thank

Comment: possible duplicate of [Magento catalog price rule disappears at night](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25280095/magento-catalog-price-rule-disappears-at-night)

Comment: am sure there is no duplication of the rules.

Comment: I was talking about duplicated question, not rules. Did you read the link? Have you tried the solution?

Comment: oh , i tried your solution but no results still i have to apply the rules to apply the price each day.